# How to display image along with other object data from mysql using struts 1.3 and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I am having trouble in displaying image blob stored in mysql database on jsp page using struts action that fetches object (including image) using hibernate. I tried 
technique but problem with this it requires some sort of ID but i do not want to do this. What my program is actually doing is once user login, user gets to see button 'mypartners'. clicking this button invokes myPartners action, which first determines userid passed from request and then fetches userPartner list from mySQl database using Hibernate. It works fine, if i do not have a blob in the database but when i add the blob 'logo' to display partner's image that is when i run into problems.

Please help and provide some code examples if possible.

Salman